# Identifying web workers environment?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Is it possible to determine whether or not Javascript is running in a Web Worker context?

Comment: You could check if the `window` object exists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the typeof [one of the objects](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/#toc-enviornment-features) (document, window, parent) that a web worker context cannot gain access to.

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of that. I suspect sleeping 4 hours in the last two days may have something to do with it. haha.